# Setup MySQL 5.6 with Macports

Tags: mysql, macos, installation, macports

MacOS 10.10, up-to-date macports. I want to get mysql 5.6 on port 3306.

1) **Installing**

```
port install mysql56-server mysql56
```

installs mysql56@5.6.22_0, after that

```
which mysql
```

or

```
which mysql56
```

returns nothing.

So first question is where is mysql client?

2) **Configuring**

Installation script suggests to do

```
sudo -u _mysql /opt/local/lib/mysql56/bin/mysql_install_db
```

then

```
/opt/local/lib/mysql56/bin/mysqladmin -u root password 'new-password'
```

which asks for running server and I start it by

```
cd /opt/local ; /opt/local/lib/mysql56/bin/mysqld_safe &
```

then *mysqladmin* complains about socket and I comment *--skip-networking* in */opt/local/etc/mysql56/macports-default.cnf* and after that command goes ok. then

```
/opt/local/lib/mysql56/bin/mysqladmin -u root -h bp.local password 'new-password'
```

which returns

```
error: 'Host '10.0.1.9' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server'
```

I really don't know what to do here without mysql client. And I'm kind of stuck.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

MacPorts installs MySQL and its derivatives in a way that they don't conflict with each other and can be installed at the same time. That includes putting the mysql binary in non-standard paths. You can locate your binary using `port contents mysql56 | grep -E '/s?bin/'`. MacPorts also comes with a selection mechanism that creates symlinks for your convenience in `/opt/local/bin`. To make MySQL 5.6 your default, run `sudo port select --set mysql mysql56`.

To start the server, you can use MacPorts' daemon control functions (that are a frontend to launchd): `sudo port load mysql56-server` will start the server and ensure it is running after a reboot, `sudo port unload mysql56-server` will undo that and stop the server.

The `--skip-networking` is the default to make running multiple MySQL versions side-by-side possible. See `port notes mysql56` for more information.

You can connect to MacPorts' MySQL using a unix socket, although I don't recall its path from the top of my head. I'm sure http://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/MAMP has them, though. To connect to your local server, you should use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` instead of `bp.local`, which apparently resolves to a private IP address and thus goes through the IP stack of your OS, rather than through the loopback interface.

Comment: I was trying `port select` but with only one hyphen :(.

And as I understand you have to install `mysql_select` to be able to use it.

@neverpanic if could you add commands for mysql start without adding to boot and for restart this answer of yours would be perfect.

Comment: `mysql56` depends on `mysql_select`, so you'll always have it installed when you have `mysql56` installed (unless you forced MacPorts to ignore the dependency). Unfortunately, launchd always keeps daemon state across reboots AFAIK, so there's no way to "start until next reboot" with launchd plists. I guess your start command would work for that case, though. Just make sure you use the same environment and user as the plist does, though.

Comment: You can find the socket path by running `/opt/local/lib/mysql56/bin/mysqladmin -u root -p variables` and looking for the line `socket`.  For me, it was: `/opt/local/var/run/mysql56/mysqld.sock`.