# MySQL connection only works through command line

Tags: mysql, linux, macos, macports

From my mac, I installed mysql56+server through macports 4 months ago.  Today after a laptop restart, I wasn't able to connect to MySQL anymore through SQL Pro.  I can only connect through the Terminal.  I have posted some relevant information below.

Command that successfully works for connecting to MySQL (after entering password):

```
/opt/local/etc/mysql56 mysql -u root -p
```

Command that fails to connect to MySQL:

```
/opt/local/etc/mysql56 mysql -u root -p -h '127.0.0.1'
Enter password: 
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61)

/opt/local/etc/mysql56 telnet 127.0.0.1 3306
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

/etc/hosts contains:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
```

The my.cnf file that I am using has everything commented out.  I do not want to use a socketed connection, just standard 127.0.0.1 connection that I was using in SQL Pro.

Comment: localhost != 127.0.0.1 and you should use localhost whenever possible. Enabling network access to your database is something that should be avoided unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 1):

In your my.cnf file, find `bind-address` and change it to (or comment out):

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
#bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

After that restart mysql and try to connect:

```
mysql.server restart
mysql -u root -p -h '127.0.0.1'
```

Comment: I tried adding the following to /opt/local/etc/mysql56/my.cnf and restarting, but am still getting the same error.
    [mysql]
    bind-address = 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of both

- [Setup MySQL 5.6 with Macports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27325754/setup-mysql-5-6-with-macports/27332765#27332765) and
- [mysql running but cannot connect to 127.0.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26538112/mysql-running-but-cannot-connect-to-127-0-0-1/26543260#26543260).

See also the output of `port notes mysql56-server`, which explains this and was printed during installation.

Comment: If it's a duplicate, flag it as such.