# Can't log in on phpMyAdmin but i can on mysql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, centos, centos7

I'm trying to log in on `PhpMyAdmin` on Centos7 but i can't.
I'm sure that the login and password of MySQL are correct because i can log in to MySQL with command line.
I'm using Mysql 8.
I tried even to change the password and created a new user. The same problem persist
The problem is when i try to connect to `phpMyAdmin`, i have this red message on the login interface:

> Connexion au serveur MySQL non permise

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: Did you try doing `Flush Privileges`?

```CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;```

Comment: Do you try this on 1 machine, or is PhpMyAdmin running on another machine then MySQL ?

Comment: finally the ``FLUSH PRIVILEGES``  must go to apply the changes.

Comment: @AnkitJindal yes i did it but it is usually the same problem. I can connect on Mysql only with command line.

Comment: @Luuk yes i'm trying to connect to phpMyAdmin on the same machine as MySQL

Comment: @JavierG.Raya The command FLUSH PRIVILEGES works on the command line but it deosn't have effects on phpMyAdmin, I can't login on phpMyAdmin

Comment: then I don't know anymore. Sorry

Comment: Please show the config used for MySQL.  i.e. [skip-networking](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_skip_networking) might cause PhpMyAdmin to stop connecting.

Comment: @Luuk How can I show the config used for MySQL please ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144508/mysql-connection-only-works-through-command-line
This answer might be helpful for you

Comment: To show the configured settings add `--print-defaults` to the complete statement that is starting `mysqld`

Comment: Are you connecting to the same exact host? To MySQL, `127.0.0.1` and `localhost` use different connection types (TCP/IP networking compared to sockets) which means permissions are also different for the two types. When you start the command line client, use the `STATUS;` command to see your connection type. The phpMyAdmin default is localhost (sockets) and at least on my system, the MySQL default is 127.0.0.1 (TCP/IP). You'll need to verify that the user you're trying to use has permissions for both sets of hosts, which usually looks like two different user accounts with different host fields.

Answer (score 0):

Try with MySQL native password, to use this login to your MySQL with the command line as you said you can. And then change the password as native password with this command:

**ALTER USER your_db_username@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'your_current_password';**

Optionally, you can change your privilege if need for any host; to change this use this command : **GRANT ALL ON * *.* * TO your_db_username@'%';**

and then use **FLUSH PRIVILEGES;** to apply the change.

And also check all the required PHP extensions are installed or not. like   **php-mbstring** if not installed, install it with the command:  **yum install php-mbstring** after that restart server if apache/httpd use the command: **systemctl restart httpd**

And then try to log in to phpMyadmin hope it works!